# Consuming Web Service from browser using other than port 80

Tags: web-services, iis, port, asmx, webmethod

I already did everything to run my webservice on IIS and it is working. IIS Pool is listening to port 81, and i did port fowarding from port 8081 to port 81 inside my network, aiming for my server. When i type http://foo.com:8081/WebServiceName.asmx it returns my web service page to consume my WebMethods. So I choose one my WebMethods, fill the parameters, and when i press Invoke Button, it changes the URL Address to http://foo.com:81/WebServiceName.asmx/WebMethodName, and since port 81 should not receive any external request, its does not respond.

What am i doing wrong, or missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since no one has acheived to solve this, i did port fowarding on 81 to my Web Server too and solved my problem.